# how to make an installer for WCF Service using wix?

Tags: wix

Can anybody tell me how to make an installer for WCF Service using wix? Is there any good tutorial for it? I know i can use  and , but there is not much documentation abt these.

Comment: Creating an installer with WiX for a WCF service is no different than an installer for any other app. Is your question about WiX in general? Or why do you ask specifically about a Wix installer for a WCF service??

Comment: thanks for your response  marc. I thought creating an installer for wcf service is different from other apps. what are the use of serviceinstall and servicecontrol elements in wix then?

Comment: @Subrat Agasti: it depends on how you plan to host your WCF service: if you host it in IIS, all you need to do is create a virtual directory in your IIS and copy some files - that's all. If you self-host in a **Windows (NT) Service**, then yes, you need the extra steps to install the Windows Service - but that's because the Windows Service needs to be installed into the registry and all - that has nothing to do with WCF per se

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I used this http://blog.tentaclesoftware.com/archive/2009/01/01/21.aspx

and also the WiX SDK docs with a index search on ServiceInstall

Comment: dead link dead link dead link

Comment: While this *broken* link may offer temporary hope before the inevitable disappointment, it is better to include the essential parts of the answer here and provide a *working* link for reference. Answers that are little more than a broken link provide little value and are likely to be downvoted and deleted.